# Allow Phonegap's inappbrowser to access phone gallery?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

Our app uses Phonegap's inappbrowser to point to our website.  Our website (written in Laravel) has an edit profile page where you can upload a profile pic.  This works fine on desktop but in the Phonegap app tapping the 'Choose Picture' button does not bring up the Android file system or gallery.  I've installed both file system plugin and file transfer plugin for Cordova and it doesn't make a difference.  Is my only choice really to re-write this part of the app custom for Phonegap using JS?

Comment: I think you might use iframe for this in your app.

Comment: Take a look at this: [http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept). If you're using the InAppBrowser, I would suggest using it with the `_system` flag to avoid issues.

Comment: @johnborges - That link seems to suggest that `<input type="file"` is completely blocked on Android versions 4.4 and up but if I use Android internet browser to navigate to our profile edit page and tap the 'Choose Picture' button it DOES open up the gallery/file chooser dialog.  Meaning that it's likely not an Android issue but in fact an inappbrowser issue.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="file"` has a lot of know errors on mobile and isn't supported with Android WebViews in general. I would suggest using the [FileTransfer Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) to accomplish what you're trying to do. Use the upload method of this plugin to manually upload the file to the remote server. Also look at the [Camera Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) to choose which image on the device to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Install the plugin cordova camera and also FileTransfer, I think that could help you much more than any kind of input, remembers working in the default browser and operating system often fail with different html attributes. There are several ways to get the picture from the device to make an upload to a server. If you're only working on Android, check your code on several devices since in some models (mostly Motorola) my fault I often a code if it works in Samsung for example. Always keep your updated plugins.

[Plugin Camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)

[FileTransfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)